# User.Identity.Name - which assembly reference brings that into your project?

Tags: c#, windows-authentication, visual-studio-2013, .net-assembly, asp.net-mvc-5

I can't find out which reference assembly the **User.Identity.Name** comes from. How do I find that out? I need to add it to a class library rather than the default MVC 5 app I have made so that I can have access to it?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user(v=vs.110).aspx

**C# Class Library / AUser.cs**

```
public class AUser
{
    public string Username
    {
        get
        {
            return User.Identity.Name // doesn't notice User
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Appears to be in the System.Web namespace.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**EDIT**

Based on your additional code, you have to include the fully qualified name - such as:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

When you are outside of a controller (or in another class).  Be aware that if this outside of MVC class is used in anything without an HttpContext, it will fail (with a NullReferenceException).  To ensure we don't have any of those, we typically either pass the HttpContext or the portions we need (Username, Url, etc) as function parameters.

Comment: @JamesT - let me see if I can dig up anything else, maybe a sub-dependent assembly.  How are you trying to call it?

Comment: tweaked the OP, hope it helps

Comment: @JamesT - Anytime!  The MvcController/View base class already has a reference to the HttpContext.Current, which is why you don't need to specify all of that in a controller or view.